# XAMPP / MySQL: getting errors during database connection

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm creating a webpage. The webpage has a form and the form data is sent through a `.php` page, to be saved in a MySQL database. I'm using XAMPP.
Here is my script:

```
  $dbc = mysqli_connect('http://localhost:8080/127.0.0.1','root',' ','aliendatabase');
  $query = "INSERT INTO aliens_abduction (first_name,last_name,when_it_happened, how_long, " .
  "how_many, alien_description, what_they_did, fang_spotted, other, email) " .
  "VALUES ('Nadreen', 'Muhammad Ali', 'since birth', '21 years', 'all of them', 'sad cretures', " .
  "'ruined me', 'yes', 'I may have seen your dog. Contact me.', " .
  "'sally@gregs-list.net')";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
  or die('Error querying database.');
  mysqli_close($dbc);
```

I keep getting those errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

And:

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/127.0.0.1` - use `'localhost'` only. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: You should use 'localhost' instead of that url. And is the password really a 'whitespace' or did you want to use a empty string '' ?

Comment: http://albertech.net/2011/05/fix-php_network_getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known/
Try this

Comment: To put it in perspective, it is looking for a hostname and it already knows the protocol (which is not http). Instead, you were confuzzling it with the http protocol, unrelated to the db lib library that would be using the mysql line protocol unrelated to http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('http://localhost:8080/127.0.0.1','root',' ','aliendatabase');
```

Use this:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','aliendatabase');
```

Comment: That space in there `' '` could be an issue here, as we all outlined in comments already. Edit: You edited.